# What should we do about a question where the OP answered it in the question itself?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question

I am talking about following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460409/sql-division-same-result-on-every-row

As we can see, the OP has found the answer and he has updated it in the question itself. What should we do when encountering such questions?

Comment: You could comment and ask the OP to post their solution as an answer, instead of in the question.

Comment: You could, but I don't see the point. How is the answer to this question ever going to help anyone else? Let's just delete it.

Comment: @Yannis - I try to do that when I see this happening, but a lot of the time it's ignored; the OP has his solution; he's given the answer; as far as he's concerned he's done with SO, so the comment probably never even gets read.

Comment: [one solution is to simply tell the op](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212042/creating-a-vbs-script-need-to-change-font-format-of-hyperlinks#comment26757598_18212042). If youre kind and quick enough to catch him before he goes off then there is a great chance it will work

Comment: (Did you notice how much Bart [improved your question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/194765/revisions) by simply fixing the title and removing non-relevant parts?)

Comment: Is there anyway that the few questions that OPs edit like this could be updated after a certain amount of time? Say after 90 days of inactivity, the question can be rolled back and the given answer  added/accepted by the Community user?  I suspect it is unlikely this could be handled automatically and would require user policing and mod intervention but would serve to clean up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways you could handle this.

- Leave a comment asking the OP to post the solution as an answer. If the OP responds and acts, great.
- If not, then rollback the edit in which the answer was added and post the solution as an answer. You could post it as a normal answer, or as a community-wiki (CW) answer. As it wasn't you who solved the problem, it would be better to post a CW answer.

  You can make an answer CW by marking the checkbox on the lower right corner.

  > [image]

Comment: I will be able to add answer as normal answer but sorry i dont know how to answer as CW answer

Comment: @Dhaval if you check the community wiki checkbox when composing the answer, then answer you post is CW

Comment: ok thank you .. i will do it .. i will answer it as CW answer